# How to specify the ordering of elements in XML by JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am using JAXB and XmlElement annotation in my Java class to generate XML files. The code looks like that

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name="COMPANY")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Company {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @XmlAttribute(name="recNo")
    private Long recid;

    @XmlElement(name="CMP_NAME")
    private String name;

    private Boolean status;

    @XmlElement(name="CMP_CODE")
    private Integer code;

    public void setCodeString(String codeName) { code = (int) codeName.charAt(0); }

    @XmlElement(name="CMP_STATUS")
    public Integer getStatusInteger() { (status)?0:1; }

    // ... other getters and setters
}
```

However, the generated elements are in CMP_NAME, CMP_CODE and CMP_STATUS while I need the order of CMP_NAME, CMP_STATUS and CMP_CODE. I cannot use XmlType.propOrder because I need to use getter in some cases. How can I specify the sequence for XmlElement?

Comment: See [`@XmlType/propOrder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlType.html#propOrder--).

Comment: @lexicore XmlType/propOrder is applicable to property fields, not to XmlElement Name tags.

Comment: Have you *actually* tried it? Because JAXB considers "property" in a model sense. Each of these `@XmlElement`s or `@XmlAttribute` is a property.
Please *do* try it and post a [MCVE] if it does not work.